# IBM Watson Speech-to-Text authentication credentials

Tags: ibm-cloud, credentials, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I am trying to run the speech to text example recipe for my TJBot. The sample config.js file needs a username and password from IBM to authenticate the service. However, IBM seems to be migrating to a API key based authentication system, and does not provide any username/password pairs. How can I connect to the service?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are referencing this [config.js](https://github.com/ibmtjbot/tjbot/blob/master/recipes/speech_to_text/config.default.js) as part of this [TJBot recipe](https://github.com/ibmtjbot/tjbot/tree/master/recipes/speech_to_text). Indeed are all the IBM Cloud services including the Watson services moving to an IAM-based authentication. Here is the [Node.js API for Speech-to-Text on authentication](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/node.html?node#authentication) which offers this way to authenticate in addition to username / password:

```
var speechToText = new SpeechToTextV1({
    iam_apikey: '{iam_api_key}',
    url: '{url}'
  });
```

Based on the layout of config.js and that API, the TTS part in your config.js should look like this:

```
// Watson Speech to Text
// https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/speech-to-text/
exports.credentials.speech_to_text = {
    iam_apikey: 'YOUR-API-KEY',
    url: 'URL-FOR-SERVICE'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The STT recipe works now. Thanks to [data_henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4923755/data-henrik) for pointing out the required config.js edit. Besides editing the config file, I also edited **node_modules/tjbot/lib/tjbot.js** at line 381 and commented out the following block:

```
//assert(credentials.hasOwnProperty('username'), "credentials for the " + service + " service missing 'username'");
//assert(credentials.hasOwnProperty('password'), "credentials for the " + service + " service missing 'password'");
    //var SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
         //this._stt = new SpeechToTextV1({
         //  username: credentials['username'],
         // password: credentials['password'
         // url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/',
         // version: 'v1'
         // });
         // break;`
```

and replaced it with this:

```
var SpeechToTextV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text/v1');
     this._stt = new SpeechToTextV1({
     iam_apikey: credentials['iam_apikey'],
     url: 'https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api',
     version: 'v1'
});
break;`
```

Answer (score 0):

@data_henrik you solution may work. But a better solution is to edit the config.js directly as follows (note the keywork is apikey, not iam_apikey):

```
// Watson Speech to Text
// https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/speech-to-text/
exports.credentials.speech_to_text = {
    apikey: 'YOUR-API-KEY',
    url: 'URL-FOR-SERVICE'
};
```